# How to make tomcat scalable with increasing number of cores?

Tags: tomcat, scalability

The tomcat doc and my googling have told me that Tomcat can scale up with the number of cores.  Developers should not need to do anything extra except make sure no unnecessary synchronization  takes place that may slow things down.

I did the following experiment:

1. A CentOS 6.0 64-bit box with 4G of RAM.
2. Enable 1 to 16 cores in different tests.
3. Tomcat 7. (No change to out of the box config other than installing the servlets below)
4. Install a Hello World servlet that only echoes the "Hello World" string back.
5. Another servlet same as above but performs some dummy calculation (e.g. adding up 1 to 1M)
6. Hit the server with 30 concurrent clients.

With the above setup, I basically see no performance difference between 1 to 16 cores.  I got similar result with any number of cores.

Since the servlet does not share anything across threads, it should be a synchronization issue.  Anyone has any clue?  Anything I may look at to investigate?

Comment: 30 concurrent clients doing what?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tune your server.xml for MaxThreads and MaxConnections? 
More information is available at:
        http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html